# Gulp task does not proceed after executing an 'open' command

Tags: gulp, xcodebuild

I am running some few gulp tasks. Whenever i reach an `open` command, it breaks by execution. Example below

```
gulp.task('xcodeIPa', ['xcodeOpen'],() =>
    run('second command').exec()
);

gulp.task('xcodeOpenProject', () =>
        run('open -a Xcode ./platforms/ios/myProject.com.xcodeproj').exec()
);
```

My xcodeOpenProject opens my xcode and does not allow the xcodeIPa to continue afterward. Please how do i open and continue ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('xcodeOpenProject', () =>
    spawn('open', ['-a', 'Xcode', './platforms/ios/myProject.com.xcodeproj'])
)
```

Note that this might end the XCode process when you terminate gulp  with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. If you want to make sure XCode keeps running even after the gulp process terminates you should pass the `detached:true` option to `spawn()`:

```
gulp.task('xcodeOpenProject', () =>
    spawn('open', ['-a', 'Xcode', './platforms/ios/myProject.com.xcodeproj'], {detached:true})
)
```